# Why is an adjustable bridge needed?

Tags: tuning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my guitar's saddle at an angle?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/why-is-my-guitars-saddle-at-an-angle)

I think my acoustic has a bridge that makes each string a slightly different length, and I'm assuming an adjustable bridge does the same thing.  Doesn't a slight change to tuning of each string have the same effect, or is it something to do with temperament?

Comment: @Alex - you're right, that's exactly the question I was trying to ask.  Can someone close my duplicate question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is all you need to know about why the bridge on your acoustic is angled: [Why is my guitar's saddle at an angle?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/why-is-my-guitars-saddle-at-an-angle)

An adjustable bridge on an electric guitar is exactly the same, but is adjustable so that it is easier to adjust the intonation settings when strings are changed or a heavier/lighter string gauge is used on the guitar.